# bash find prints file twice when used expression

Tags: bash

Why are the files printed twice?

```
find . *.{h,cc} -maxdepth 1 -type f
./file7.h
./file8.h
./file9.cc
file7.h
file8.h
file9.cc
```

Is this correct? How do I specify file patterns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there twice because it's finding it first under `.`, and then under the actual filename as given to `find` as a place to search. Perhaps you meant to use `-name` while escaping the wildcards.

Comment: How should I change this to include -name?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \( -name \*.h -o -name \*.cc \) -type f
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're merely looking for files in the current directory, why not simply use:

```
 $ shopt -s expglob
 $ ls *.*(h|cc) */*.*(h|cc)
```

Otherwise, you have to do something liek this:

```
 $ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cc" \)
```

Using parentheses will do the or first, then combine it with the -type f and -maxdepth.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name *.h -o -name *.cc -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Comment: Needs parentheses, because -o has a low priority.

Answer (score 0):

`find *.{h,cpp} -maxdepth 1 -type f`
This maybe help .

Comment: @Mark why ? it works , and it seems that *.{h,cpp} indicates the path although I am not sure

Comment: You are searching the entire tree I just want the current directory.

Comment: @Mark `You are searching the entire tree I just want the current directory`  
**Did you try it ?**

Comment: It completely missed my `.foo.cpp`.